# jQuery AJAX works in Django server but not in Apache

Tags: django, ajax, apache

I have a Django application with a form that retrieves some information with AJAX using jQuery:

```
$('#id_doi').focusout(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "{% url 'get-doi' %}" + "?doi=" + $('#id_doi').val(),
        dataType: 'json',
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log('error ' + textStatus);
        },
        success: function(result) {
            $('#id_title').val(result.title);
            if (result.new_journal_entry != '') {
                $("#id_journal").append(new Option(result.new_journal_entry, result.new_journal_id))    
            }                   
            $('#id_reference').val(result.this_reference);
            $("#id_journal").removeAttr("selected");
            $("#id_journal").find('option:contains("' + result['container-title'] + '")').attr("selected", true);
            $("#id_pubdate").attr('value', result.issued['date-parts'][0][0]);

            $("#id_status").removeAttr("selected").find('option:contains("published")').attr("selected", true)
        }

    });
})
```

The corresponding view function is:

```
@login_required
def get_doi(request):   
    cmd = '/usr/bin/curl -LH "Accept: application/rdf+xml;q=0.5, application/vnd.citationstyles.csl+json;q=1.0" https://doi.org/' + request.GET['doi']
    retval = os.popen(cmd).read()

    cmd = '/usr/bin/curl -LH "Accept: text/x-bibliography; style=apa" https://doi.org/' + request.GET['doi']
    ref = os.popen(cmd).read()

    data = json.loads(retval)

    data['this_reference'] = ref

    qs = Journals.objects.filter(name=data['container-title'])
    if len(qs) == 0:
        journal = Journals(
                name = data['container-title'],
                extra_info = 'Created by DOI lookup.'
            )

        journal.save()
        data['new_journal_entry'] = data['container-title']
        data['new_journal_id'] = str(journal.pk)

    else:
        pass

    retval = json.dumps(data)

return HttpResponse(retval, content_type='application/json')
```

This calls `os.popen()` function to execute `curl` command. I think that perhaps the problem is somehow related to this.

This works fine in Django server, but in Apache it gives `Server Error (500)` and the only thing that appears in the Apache `error.log` file is this table:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
100   193  100   193    0     0    773      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   775

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
100  9276  100  9276    0     0   8809      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:-- 15938
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
100   193  100   193    0     0    876      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   877

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
100   356  100   356    0     0    334      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--   551
```

I don't have idea what this table means but apparently they appear after executing the `os.popen()` calls. Any ideas why this doesn't work in Apache?

Answer (score 0):

I will answer my question since no one did it yet.

The problem is with Apache permissions to execute shell commands. So, I had to resort to the `requests` module to achieve the same by doing something like this:

```
headers = {"Accept":"application/rdf+xml;q=0.5, 
application/vnd.citationstyles.csl+json;q=1.0"}
retval = requests.get('https://doi.org/' + request.GET['doi'], headers=headers)
```

You are welcome!